# Visual studio code + Angular error highlighting not working while files are open

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

The angular error highlighting messaging is not working in VS Code for me (or is it supposed to be like this?).

What happens is:
1. If I add a `ngModel` and bind it to an event on my model.
2. Add the event in my model.

Visual studio code still gives the error that it won't find the event even though it's there.

Usually it is solved if I close all the files in visual studio code. Sometimes it just takes a very long time.

Is there anyone who have experienced this and have a solution? Better tooling? I'm not quite sure what is causing this, I may have some extension in visual code or if it's built in.

[image: See this image for the issue]

Comment: I face that too, it gets corrected simply by inputing a bit of code in your template. Annoying at first, but then you learn to live with it.

Comment: Yah don't think it's just VS code, even on using webstorm at work I experienced something similar.